# ¿Cómo ejecutar un eventos en orden al dar click a un elemento?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Buenas tardes comunidad,

mi problema, radica en que tengo una librería de javascript de un sdk que estoy utilizando en el trabajo, pero por más que intenté utilizarla con typescript no pude, por lo que decidí ver de que manera utilizarlo mediante el html, haciendo pruebas vi que si abría una etiqueta de script en el html, podía hacer uso de las propiedades de esta librería y luego invocar la función creada en el index desde cualquier otro componente. El asunto es que necesito pasarle un parametro a esta funcion que recojo desde mi componente de typescript, por lo que primero intento cargar el parametro en un input y luego, tomar el valor de ese input y mandarlo a la función de javascript. Mi problema es que para hacer uso de la función de javascript en el index, tengo que usar el evento onclick y para recoger el dato de typescript necesito el evento (click), sin embargo, se ejecuta la funcion de javascript primero que la de typescript y necesito que vaya primero la de typescript.
Les dejo las funciones para que puedan entender mejor el problema:

Función para recoger el parametro desde typescript:

```
seleccionarImagen(index: number) {
this.texto = this.archivos[index].ArchivoImg;
}
```

función de javascript:

```
  <script>
    function loadFile(file) {
      if (file != null) {
          var params = {
              Value: file,
              Example: false
          };
          console.log(params.Value);
          DocuViewareAPI.PostCustomServerAction(
              "DocuVieware1", true, "loadFile", params, 
               function(result){ 
                 console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
               }
          );
      }
    }   
    </script>
```

Elemento donde quiero utilizar los metodos:

```
<tr *ngFor="let archivo of archivos; let i = index;" 
    (click) = "seleccionarImagen(i);" 
    onclick="loadFile(txtTexto.value);">
```

Viendo el elemento anterior, lo que quiero es que el método loadFile se ejecute después de que haya terminado el de seleccionarImagen, pero no es así, se ejecuta primero el de loadFile. Entonces, quisiera saber si sabían como puedo hacer para que se ejecute ese evento primero. Y de ser posible, si saben como puedo utilizar la librería en typescript ni cosa mejor, para eso lo que he intentado es esto:

```
import * as docuvieware from '../../../docuvieware/docuvieware-min.js';
```

y agregando en el constructor una variable del tipo docuvieware o utilizando el docuvieware a secas, pero no puedo acceder a los elementos desde mi componente de typescript.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que hice al final, fue crear un archivo de javascript que contuviese esas funciones y luego usar exportar las funciones como módulos para luego importar ese archivo en typescript.

Archivo de js:

```
module.exports = { loadFile: 
function loadFile(file) {
console.log(file);
if (file != null) {
    var params = {
        Value: file,
        Example: false
    };
    var result = DocuViewareAPI.PostCustomServerAction("DocuVieware1", true, "loadFile", params, function(result){ console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(result)); }).Value;
    console.log(result);
}
```

};

Importación:

import * as docuvieware from './docuvieware';

De esta manera podemos hacer todo desde ts utilizando el evento (click).

Saludos.